# Nmap NSE script function is behaving differently if the argument is a hardcoded string or a variable containing said string

Tags: lua, scripting, dns, nmap

i'm trying to write a Nmap NSE DNS bruteforce script for a school work.
my problem is that when using the function : `dns.query(dname,options)`
where dname is a FQDN, the result is different is the argument is

1: A hardcoded string like this

```
local status, result = dns.query("www.domain.com", {dtype="A",retAll=true})
```

or 2: a variable made in the function match that concatenates two strings

```
local status, result = dns.query(domain, {dtype="A",retAll=true})
```

```
local function match(sub,host)
        local domain = print(sub.."."..host.name)
        local status, result = dns.query(domain, {dtype="A",retAll=true})
        if status == "true" then
                return domain
        end
        return ''
end
```

debug mode shows that the variable domain is indeed equal to the same value as the hardcoded string. But the behavior is different.

what could cause this sort of problem ?

docs for dns library : https://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/dns.html

Comment: `local domain = print(sub.."."..host.name)`  Usually `print()` returns `nil`

Comment: it must be: `local domain = sub.."."..host.name`